# Passing array through function with Key names php?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to pass an array that has defined keys into a function parameter, but when I call the function it creates it's own set of numeric keys for the array. How can I make it use the same keys?

```
<?php

$param = [
"foo" => "bar",
"bar" => "foo",
];

function amazonRequest($AmazonQuery) {
    $url = array();
    foreach ($AmazonQuery as $key => $val) {

    $key = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($key));
    $val = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($val));
    $url[] = "{$key}={$val}";

    print_r($url);
 }
}

amazonRequest($param);
print_r($param);
```

Comment: `$url[$key] = "{$key}={$val}";` perhaps? If I understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are autonumbering an empty array:

`$url[] = "{$key}={$val}";`

Of course it will be numbered starting from 0.
You can use  `$url[$key] = "{$key}={$val}";` if you want the keys to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

When you add new items to an array using: `$array[] = "something"`, it will add an indexed key `[0 => 'something', ...]` always starting at 0.

If you want to add a new item with an associative key (non sequenced or string) you need to define the key name:

```
// Since you get the key in your foreach loop, just add it like this:
$url[$key] = "{$key}={$val}";
```

The new `$url`-array should now look like:

```
[
    "foo" => "foo=bar",
    "bar" => "bar=foo"
]
```